# Does adding a new APFS container damage data on the volume?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, filesystem, apfs

This question sounds very basic, but I have not found the answer.

In disk utility I can add a new APFS volumes to an (external) disk. Does this operation affect data already on the disk?

I know that similar operations on windows and linux does not affect the data, but just to be sure, are there any existing documentation for macOS and APFS about this?

Comment: Are you using a Intel or Apple Silicon Mac?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Apple Silicon.

Comment: The answer should be "no". But question is confused: 2nd para talks about adding *volume*, title says *container*. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definitely NO. Unless you directly delete a partition or a volume, the data is not affected. A volume in APFS is like a partition, but it can resize to share space with other partitions, instead of the size being set at creation. A container holds ALL volumes and partitions and can not be deleted, only erased. There can not be more than one container on a drive.